# Create checkpoint, coordinator and changelog kafka topics in separate cluster when using Samza

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-samza, apache-kafka-connect

When using kafka with samza, samza is auto creating certains topics such as checkpoint, co-oridnator and changelog using the names from the properties file. But these topics are created in the same cluster.

But for maintenance purpose, I want to create them in a separate cluster, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can configure a System for each cluster and set the values for 
`task.checkpoint.system`, `job.coordinatior.system` and `stores.<storename>.changelog` so that each of them points to a different cluster/system.

Here's the config documentation for reference:
http://samza.apache.org/learn/documentation/0.11/jobs/configuration-table.html